# The Spotify API callback url has '#' in it instead of '?' how to access parameters in python django

Tags: python, django, oauth, spotify

I am using the Implicit grant authorization (1 of 3) types of authorization provided by Spotify.

The callback url looks something like this
`http://localhost:8000/callback/#access_token=BQDRRPQ1Nulwcxx...mFNtnTsVUNlkCg&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600&state=NtiLgMVtLPx926Ay`

If it was
`http://localhost:8000/callback/**?**access_token`

Then I am able to obtain the query parameters using `request.GET` in my view, but since it has **#**, `request.GET` returns empty dictionary.

I also tried `request.build_absolute_uri()`, but it returns just    `http://localhost:8000/callback/`

Here is how my view looks

```
def callback(request, format=None):
    print(request.GET)
    if "access_token" in request.GET:
        print(request.GET["access_token"])

    return HttpResponse("Callback")
```

I was expecting `request.GET` to have the `access_token`, expires in and the parameters that are in the URI, but I'm getting empty dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Implicit grant authorization flow used by Spotify, the access token and other parameters are typically included in the fragment identifier (after the '#') of the callback URL. However, the fragment identifier is not sent to the server by the browser, so you won't be able to retrieve those parameters using request.GET in your Django view.

Instead, you can access the fragment identifier and its parameters using JavaScript on the client-side. Here's an example of how you can retrieve the access token using JavaScript and then send it to your server:

```
const fragmentString = window.location.hash.substring(1); // Get the fragment identifier without the '#'
const params = new URLSearchParams(fragmentString); // Parse the parameters
const accessToken = params.get('access_token'); // Retrieve the access_token parameter

// Send the access token to your server using an AJAX request
const url = 'http://your-server-endpoint';
const data = { access_token: accessToken };

fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
  .then(response => {
    // Handle the server's response
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Handle errors
  });
```

On your server-side, you can define a separate endpoint to handle the access token sent by the JavaScript code:

```
# Django view to handle the access token
from django.http import JsonResponse

def handle_token(request):
    access_token = request.POST.get('access_token')
    # Process the access_token as needed
    return JsonResponse({'message': 'Access token received'})
```

Make sure to set up the appropriate URL routing in your Django application to handle the callback and the token handling endpoints.

By using JavaScript to retrieve the access token from the fragment identifier and sending it to your server, you can work around the limitation of the fragment identifier not being included in the server's request parameters.

Comment: Yeah, I tried my best to keep it all in the server, my last resort was to make use of  client side. But anyway since you have justified it, I'll go with it. Thanks